# Error al consumir un servicio REST publicado en el puerto 8080 desde mi aplicacion angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Tengo un projecto SpringBoot el cual expone servicios rest en el puerto 8080 y que me traen data de una base de datos mysql. Todos los metodos del servicio responden correctamente ( insert, update, select, delete). Y teno mi aplicacion en angular la cual es publicada en el puerto 4200. Dentro de esta aplicacion estoy tratando de consumir los servicios del proyecto springboot pero se muestra el siguiente error. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es el service donde hago referencia al los servicios:
El path correcto de mi servicio es http://localhost:8080/mantenimiento/eventos
Pero mi aplicacion angular esta llamando al servicio con el puerto donde se ha publicado la aplicacion el 4200
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente agregando la anotacion @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200") a mi controlador de springboot pero me sigue mostrando el mismo error.

Agradeceria me puedan ayudar con este problema.

Comment: El problema es que estas llamando a la url del front, debes establecer en baseUrl localhost:8080 que es la del backend

Comment: Bryan estas utilizando los environments que Angular te brinda?

Answer (score 0):

En tú baseUrl debes indicarle el contexto de tú servicio de manera correcta http://localhost:8080/mantenimientos, al no indicarle un contexto toma el contexto actual de tu servidor localhost:4200 que es donde se está ejecutando tu aplicación angular.

También puedes utilizar variables de entornos para indicar los paths de tus urls de acuerdo al ambientest [envs](https://angular.io/guide/build)

Answer (score 0):

**Opcional**

Como [@cjara](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/27861/cjara) mencionó, debes incluir `http://localhost:8080/mantenimientos` en tu variable `baseUrl` o en su defecto puedes usarlo agregando un archivo `proxy.conf.json` en la raíz de esta manera:

```
{
    "/baseUrl/": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/baseUrl/": ""
        },
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Y en tu servicio EventoService tendrías algo así:

```
return this.http.get('baseUrl/mantenimientos/eventos')
```

Si te das cuenta, son comillas sencillas (no backticks) porque al levantar el proyecto Angular sustituye `baseUrl` por `http://localhost:8080`

Finalmente puedes levantar tu proyecto así:

```
ng serve --port 4200 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --live-reload --watch
```

Puedes revisarlo aquí [Angular CLI proxy configuration](https://itnext.io/angular-cli-proxy-configuration-4311acec9d6f)